# python find values in json related to value

Tags: python, json, key

Hi i have a python script that opens a json file, search for a value and return other parameters related to it.
Currently i'm not able to search the value inside it.

Below my json structure:

```
{
    "MALE": [{
        "name": "John",
        "age": "70",
        "country": "Germany"
    },
    {
        "name": "Luke",
        "age": "35",
        "country": "France"
    }],
    "FEMALE": [{
        "name": "Sarah",
        "age": "29",
        "country": "Spain"
    }]
}
```

What i have on python side is:

```
import json

with open('/path/to/json/file') as f_json:
     data = json.load(f_json)
```

What i want to do is:
get "age" and "country" values parsing "John" name

How could i do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code, might need some iterations to fit your exact use case

```
import json

with open('/path/to/json/file') as f_json:
    data = json.load(f_json)
    male, female = data.get("MALE"), data.get("FEMALE")
    for person in male:
        if person.get("name") == "John":
            print(person.get("age"), person.get("country")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refactor the result with a new dict if you use this logic more frequently:

```py
import json

result = {}

with open('/path/to/json/file') as f_json:
    data = json.load(f_json)
    for key in data:
        for ele in data[key]:
            result[ele['name']] = ele
```

Then you can use result to access relative property of some name:

```py
result['John']['age']
result['John']['country']
```